# Is it possible implement adobe flash player in android

Tags: android, flash, shockwave

I want play shockwave videos in android but there is no support for .swf in android. Instead of using WebView to play .swf files is it possible to implement adobe flash?

Comment: Why do you call it "shockwave video"?? If your SWF has just vector animation (no code etc) then maybe try ffmpeg for android to convert to a temp video file (MP4) during runtime. The nearest to _"...implement flash"_ is to just create your Android app via Flash itself (the coding tool that makes SWF with extra effort can also output APK). You'll have to learn AS3 which works similar to Java.

Comment: K thanks I'll try this, but one more question in Youtube android app how they implemented .swf file? @VC.One

Comment: How do you mean by Youtube has implemented SWF file?

Comment: I can play those videos in youtube app thats why. @VC.one

Comment: If you're talking about uploading & editing, then it's because Youtube converts all video formats uploaded to MP4, FLV & OGV. The website handles any A/V format because it's supposedly **[powered by FFmpeg](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/googles-youtube-uses-ffmpeg/)** so its safe to assume same thing for Android & iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

As I got know that Adobe abandoned Flash for Android

Comment: How is this an answer? Yes they dropped Flash plugin for mobile browsers and same time started making Flash (coding tool) have options to output for Android and iOS. See **[this image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COjKUOSU8AADT_t.png:large)**, under _"Create New"_ the option _"AIR for Android"_ is what compiles project as APK instead of SWF. That (Flash CC) APK could load SWF data but not possible if APK is made with Android SDK. Anyways are you making a media player? Your real answer is to use FFmpeg for Android SDK to handle SWF data.